# Runner on third base catches a soft line drive

Tags: baseball

I just had this happen last night at a 14u game.  We were up 12 to 1 at the time, so it didn't end up being a big deal. The runner at third base was clearly in foul territory and caught a soft line drive which was going over his head. He actually reached up to snag the ball out of the air. Our third baseman was moving to possibly make a play on the ball. I'm not saying that he would have made the play, but he would have been close.  The ump just called it foul, and let the game proceed.  We did end up winning 12-10.  I would assume the runner should be out.

Comment: This is interesting because not only should the batter be out - for sure - but there is also a case to be made for the runner being out.   There are two rules that come to mine although I am too lazy to look them up.   #1 unsportsmanlike conduct - basically runner is out and possibly kicked out of the game.   Same thing if I hear the runner at 3rd calling the pitcher a pu**y.  It happens.   #2  How I would rule it is give the team that interfered the worst possible outcome.   That would be the 3rd baseman catching ball and tagging 3rd for double play.

Answer (score 6):

According to the 14U rules [here:](https://bsbproduction.s3.amazonaws.com/portals/4577/docs/baseballrules/14u%20baseball/14u%20baseball%20rules.pdf)

[The Official Baseball Rules](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf) are the first in the order of precedence to specify a rule for this scenario.

According to The Official Baseball Rules

- Rule 5.09(b)3) - *A runner is out when ...* He intentionally interferes with a thrown ball; or hinders a
  fielder attempting to make a play on a batted ball

The runner should have been out.

Comment: Make sure you put something in there about the hitter being out - but good answer.

Comment: Is there a reason the hitter is out with certainty?